# Building a hash inside a function

Tags: krl

I have a function that returns a hash, given certain parameters:

```
build_message = function(from, to, bcc, subject, tag, htmlbody, textbody, replyto) {
    message = {"From": from,
        "To": to,
        "Subject": subject,
        "HtmlBody": htmlbody,
        "TextBody": textbody};
    message.encode();
}
```

Some of these parameters, like `bcc` and `replyto` are optional. If the caller provides null values for them, they must not be present in the hash I return. That is to say, `"Bcc": bcc` must only be present in the hash if the `bcc` argument is non-null.

Here is my first attempt, but the parser doesn't like it (this goes right before the `message.encode()` line of the function):

```
bcc_body = bcc => {"Bcc": bcc} | {};
message.put(bcc_body);
```

Is using the `put()` operation allowed on a variable inside a function like this? If so, is something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.put()` inside a function, but remember that it returns a new hash and leaves the original unmodified.

Try ending your method like this:

```
bcc_body = bcc => {"Bcc": bcc} | {};
newmessage = message.put(bcc_body);
newmessage.encode();
```

Comment: Can I chain them? For example: `newmessage = message.put(first_hash).put(second_hash).put(third_hash);`

Comment: yes, chaining works. remember that you can also put an expression that resolves to a hash instead of a hash itself: newmessage = message.put(bcc => {"Bcc": bcc} | {});